# API Promises in multiple .map functions

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a table in Node.JS with some JIRA API data.

My problem is that I need to go through multiple .map functions and inside those, I need to make multiple API calls but promises don't wait for those API calls to be finished before sending data to the frontend.

Right now I have something like:

```
await Promise.all(epics.map(async (epic) =>{
    return Promise.all(sprintsTable.map((sprints, key) => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            jira.epic.getIssuesForEpic({
                boardId: board_id,
                epicId: epic.id,
                jql:  'sprint='+sprints.id
            }, function (error, issues){
                var task = {
                    title: 'TASK',
                    data: issues,
                };
                resolve(task);

            });
        });

    }));
})).then((response) => {

});
```

Right now, by server.js send a 200 respond before the api call is actually executed so it doesn't wait for all the .map and apis call to be executed.

Comment: Where's data being sent to the front-end too early?  It's not clear what isn't waiting for what?  You do realize that you're calling all your `jira.epic.getIssuesForEpic)` calls in parallel, right?  This does not sequence them.  It sends them all out and then waits for all of them to be done.  I'd also suggest you remove the `async` from the first `.map()` callback as it is not needed.  It's also odd that you are using both `await` and `.then()` on the top level `Promise.all()`.  Typically, you'd use one or the other.

Comment: And, you also need error handling on your `jira.epic.getIssuesForEpic()` call.  You are currently ignoring the `error` argument to your callback.

Comment: We need to see the surrounding code where you are actually sending the 200 response to the front-end.  That's likely where the issue is.